# How to add addTextChangedListener to listview values from sqlite database as source in editText for Android?

Tags: android, listview, listener, android-edittext

I would like to have editText addTextChangedListener to listview values for sqlite database values.Kindly provide me a snippet or example to do this or is it not possible to do it.Kindly provide a snippet to achieve this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom adapter and in the `getView` method add the text change listener to you edit text.